# Finding accounts over limits using SQL

Tags: sql

Hey everyone I was presented with a challenge recently that I failed but wanted to try and figure out.  This was during an interview:

There are two tables

Transactions

```
-Name nvarchar
-Days nvarchar
-Amount int
```

Limits

```
-Day int
-Week int
```

The task was to find transactions that went over the limits.  And if there were none, then the query should return "None."

The expected output was John.

The data was as follows:

for Transactions:

[image]

for Limits:

[image]

And yes there is no relationships in the tables.

Any suggestions?  I have code but I'm not even going to bother because my train of thought was clearly incorrect.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Only tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: Understood.  Thank you